# Not sure how to properly use Matrix4.LookAt in this situation

Tags: c#, opengl, matrix, glsl, opentk

I am experimenting with ray marching, and have been following [Jamie Wong's tutorial.](http://jamie-wong.com/2016/07/15/ray-marching-signed-distance-functions/)

When the moving the camera section comes, they use the function

```c
mat4 viewMatrix(vec3 eye, vec3 center, vec3 up) {
    vec3 f = normalize(center - eye);
    vec3 s = normalize(cross(f, up));
    vec3 u = cross(s, f);
    return mat4(
        vec4(s, 0.0),
        vec4(u, 0.0),
        vec4(-f, 0.0),
        vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1)
    );
}
```

To generate a matrix that can be used to transform the direction vector so that the camera looks at the right object.

I wanted to move the matrix calculation out of the shader though, since it would be a better fit as a uniform, and so I did, but OpenTK's function `Matrix4.LookAt()` produces very different results, and I'm not sure how to apply them to the ray with the simple multiplication that Jamie's function gave.

I have confirmed that the matrix is being loaded into the uniform correctly, it just doesn't apply to the direction vector in the same way.

Edit: I am aware that I can translate Jamie Wong's function from GLSL into C#, but I want to know the correct usage of Matrix4.LookAt.

Comment: well, the `viewMatrix` function you're quoting isn't a "LookAt" function as it is typically used in the context of computer graphics; your function only sets up a _rotation matrix_ and does not do a translation based on the `eye` position. It is at least very unfortunate that it uses the parameters `eye` and `center` if it really only is interested in the view direction, and really misleads the users to think it might create a `lookAt` matrix (not sure if intentional or not)

Comment: @derhass That makes sense then. So the is the LookAt function relevant at all or should I just translate the viewMatrix function to C#?

Comment: Well, it is even worse. It is called `viewMatrix` but creates the _inverse_ of what we typically call a view matrix (which is supposed to transform from _world_ space into view space).  Conceptually, the code does the same as `Transpose(LookAt( (0,0,0), center-eye, up))` would do.

Comment: Note that nothing is wrong with this code per say - doing the inverse transform totally makes sense for ray casting, it just doesn't fit into the concept - and _terminology_ - which those matrix helper functions like `LookAt` meant for rasterization pipelines use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenTK offers the data types `Vector3`, `Vector4` and `Matrix4` in the `OpenTK.Mathematics` namespace.

Assuming you have the vectors:

```cs
Vector3 center;
Vector3 eye;
Vector3 up;
```

Calculate the view matrix as follows

```cs
var f = Vector3.Normalize(center - eye);
var s = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.Cross(f, up));
var u = Vector3.cross(s, f);
var viewMatrix = new Matrix4(
    new Vector4(s, 0.0f),
    new Vector4(u, 0.0f),
    new Vector4(-f, 0.0f),
    new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0,0f, 1.0f),
);
```

A uniform of type `mat4` can be set with `GL.UniformMatrix4`. For example:

```c
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
```

```
int viewMatrixLoc = GL.GetUniformLocation(0, "viewMatrix");
GL.UniformMatrix4(viewMatrixLoc, false, ref viewMatrix);
```

---

Your "view matrix" transforms from view space into world space. It transforms a "view" ray into the world.
`Matrix4.LookAt` does the opposite. It computes a matrix that transforms world space to view space. It generates a matrix for rasterization, in which an object must be transformed from the world into the view.
So you need to [invert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) the matrix that you get from `Matrix4.LookAt`:

```cs
Matrix4 viewMatrix = Matrix4.LookAt(
    new Vector3(0.0f),
    center - eye,
    up
).Inverted();
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can just translate Jamie's function to C#, but I would like to know how to properly use the built in Matrix4.LookAt method for this situation if it is applicable. I should have made that more clear in my question, sorry.

Comment: @Salmon I've extended the answer.